# Matplotlib venn3 one of 7 subsets not displaying

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-venn

The 10350 section will not display using the following code:

```
from matplotlib_venn import venn3
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
venn3(subsets = (11204, 86609, 133919, 7609, 10350, 109510, 279942), set_labels = ('Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3'))
```

[image]

...but if I change 7609 to 76090 or I change 10350 to 20000 then it displays...

[image]
[image]

Ideas?

**UPDATE - For what it's worth, I also tested sending full set detail to venn3 to allow venn3 to determine the overlaps and I got the same result.  I also confirmed all of the set/overlap counts using intersection() and symmetric_difference() and all of the numbers check out.**

Comment: I'm encountering the same problem. Were you able to find a solution? Thanks!